# C Pointer Subtraction

Tags: c, pointers, syntax

I am having problem about subtraction of pointers one another.

```
char a[] = "abcdefghijkl";
a2 = 'g';
a3 = "jkl";
*a4, *a5;

a4 = strchr(a,a2);
a5 = strstr(a,a3);

printf("%s\n", a+6);
printf("%c\n", *a);
printf("%c\n", *(++a4));
printf("%c\n", ++(*a4));
printf("%ld\n", a5-a4);
printf("%s\n", &a[2]);
```

1. printf function prints : ghijkl
2. printf function prints : a
3. printf function prints : h
4. printf function prints : i
5. printf function prints : 2
6. printf function prints : cdefgiijkl

5. and 6. are problematic for me.
The last form of a4 points to 'i' and a5 is to 'j'. In this situation, I think I should have taken 1 as a result of a5-a4.
The last one is also complicated for me. I just needed it to be 'c'.

Comment: please add an MCVE _https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve_

Comment: @CIsForCookies The only thing missing from the code given to make it a full MCVE is `main()`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice And `#include <string.h>`, and `#include <stdio.h>`, and `int`, and `{`, and `}`.

Comment: and `char` before `a2...a5`. I think it's a good idea to introduce these keywords

Comment: The main problem here is that you are attempting to overwrite constant strings.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Where?

Comment: What data types are a2 and a3?

Comment: Have you stepped through this code in a debugger? Or even printed the values in hex? Printf will treat a pointer as pointing to characters terminated with a null with %s, why would it stop at the 'c'?

Comment: `a5 = strchr(a,a3);`, here `a3` is string and `strchr()` expects an int as second parameter. Aren't you getting warning for it?

Comment: My bad, I was thinking of `strcp()` instead of `strchr()`.

Comment: @chux `strcpy()` then =p My fingers are slower than my brain.

Comment: @chux melpomene already pointed out all the other syntactical pieces which are missing.

Answer (score 1):

`++(*a4)` changes the character that `a4` points to. It does not change `a4`. `a4` remains pointing to two characters before `a5`.

Answer (score 0):

This code:
printf("%s\n", &a[2]);

will print until a null terminator is encountered, which is at the end of a[] as it's initialized. It won't stop after the char at a[2]. You need a different format specifier or you need to insert a null terminator after the '2'.